# Editing Google App Script manifesto to add to home screen?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-devtools, manifest, homescreen

I have been following this codelab to fit my purpose of adding a Google App Script html service page to home-screen on a mobile device:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#1

However I am not creating a Web Server for Chrome, is it possible to achieve this with the html service?

At the moment of editing the manifesto and republishing as web app it reverts any changes done to it. I have attempted to host my json manifesto on external sites and DevTools still cannot detect it.

My index.html from App Script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="manifest" href="https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gst5h">

</head>
<body>
Some HTML..
</body>
</html>
```

My Google App Script Web App is fully functional and can be accessed through a the /exec link, I want to implement it to mobile home-screen but I don't know if the manifesto is truly being edited as upon publishing it reverts any changes done to it.

Comment: You left out a body closing tag `</body>`

Comment: Here's a simple [web app example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45968519/7215091).

Comment: Are you trying to do a PWA?

Comment: Yes I am attempting to do something as close to a PWA, as the codelabs tutorial, just something that will let me choose an icon, and splash screen.

Comment: Thanks Cooper for providing a web app example, as mine is too big to handle for demonstration purposes, I left out the body closing tag accidentally when cleaning for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Scripts are published in iframes. Where is your manifesto located? In the Play store or in the App Script? If it is in the Apps Script it it is likely the the manifesto doesn't make it to the client.

Comment: The manifesto can be found when you click inside the editor > view > show manifesto file. I also attempted to upload a json manifesto on external site, as in my code example.